# Training with extremely imbalanced Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, yolo, imbalanced-datasets, real-time

I have a object detection problem which has extremely imbalanced dataset. Lets say there is only one class to detect, say apple or not apple. This detection network will be used in a **real case** including **IP camera streaming** where positive/negative samples ratio is extremely huge, **`1:1Million`**.

My first idea to train the model with using a dataset of `100:100k` positive/negative samples ratio but the model still might be skewed to negative samples which might results in not detecting apples apparently.

I have two questions. My questions are:

- **What are the best approaches to this imbalanced dataset problem ?**
- Since I am using high resolution camera, detecting apples from camera streaming is related with **small object detection problem** since the apples in stream is really small compared the resolution of the camera. I know that **Yolo** is doing some data augmentation to improve accuracy but would it be enough to detect small objects? Should I used some **image tiling** techniques? If someone has experience about small object detection problem and know how to handle this, any idea would be perfect.

P.S: I am using Yolov4 with [AlexeyAB's Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) as a object detection model. Also, background of images are mostly the same due to Camera view.